# Deny access to .xml from users but allow bots to crawl

Tags: xml, block, bots

How do i block users to access directly .xml file from .httacess but allow google,msn or yahoo bots to still crawl and access that file ?

My httacess :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ /sitemap.php [L]
</IfModule>

## EXPIRES CACHING ##
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/png "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType text/css "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/html "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/pdf "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access 1 year"
ExpiresDefault "access 1 month"
</IfModule>
## EXPIRES CACHING ##
```

Answer (score 0):

Err... Start by asking all bot owners what is the complete list of IP addresses their bots will query your site from, so that you can allow only these IPs to get a response.

They will refuse to answer (and just ignore the question), for multiple reasons including they don't like when their bots get different results than normal users, as it's essentially trying to manipulate them into thinking you offer content you don't actually offer. So you will stay forever stuck at this step and don't need to know the next ones.

Comment: I just want to protect my sitemap from auto refreshing by users . The file exceed 14 k links and i get time out if someone try to load multiple times my sitemap .

Comment: No one but bots is interested in your sitemap. Users don't try to get it and don't participate in what you're observing.